# How can I display a div ONLY if it is not a certain term page

Tags: php, terms, conditional-tags

Ok so I have two Custom Taxonomies of "Types" and "Countries" with dozens of terms.

I basically use the terms of "Types" and "Countries" as a filter for my products in my taxonomy.php

Now Those 2 filters of "Types" and "Countries" are on the left and my products are all displaying on the rite. What I want is to **NOT** show countries categories `if im on a certain term`.

I tried using `has_term` but it did not work.

So lets say this is my category filter on my page to the left:

```
<div class="countries">
-country
-country
-country
</div>
```

I only want to display that `IF IT IS NOT THE TERM OF JUICE.`

So this is how my code currently looks:

```
<?php if ( !has_term('juice', 'types' ) ): ?>
<div class="countries">
<p>Country</p>
<ul>
<?php

//get the current term
$current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );

//then set the args for wp_list_categories
 $args = array(
  'child_of' => $current_term->term_id,
  'taxonomy' => 'countries',
  'hide_empty' => 1,
  'order'      => 'ASC',
  'show_count'     => 1,
  'hierarchical' => true,
  'depth'  => 1,
  'title_li' => ''
    );
 wp_list_categories( $args );
?>
</ul>

</div><!--countries end-->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Just need help with the correct conditional to tell that if is not in the category(term) of juice then display the countries filter but if it is in the term of juice then do NOT display the countries term list div. (because juices do not have countries)

```
<?php if ( !has_term('juice', 'types' ) ): ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [`is_tax()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax)and not `has_term()`. `has_term()` just basically checks if a post belongs to a given term, while `is_tax()` on the otherhand checks whether or not you are on a taxonomy archive page.

So, you can change this code

```
if ( !has_term('juice', 'types' ) ):
```

to

```
if ( !is_tax( 'types', 'juice' ) ):
```

This simply means that if the current taxonomy archive page is not of the term `juice`, do something

Comment: Ahh I see, well that can be a little confusing. You would think they have an is_term. Thanks a lot Pieter really appreciate it!

Comment: Yes, some of function names are a bit misleading sometimes. Glad it worked out for you. Enjoy :-)